LTspice sofware Zener diode model 3bdc missing
I cannot find any models for LTspice for Zener diode breakdown voltage of 3 V. I need Zener diode because I am trying to get simple voltage stabilizer and my load cannot handle more than 3 V. I cannot use voltage divider because many of these load and my power source supplies this and another 5 V DC load and 10 V DC loads. I do not want IC as I want to build my own voltage regulation. Does anyone know where I can find model for LTspice?

I don't know about 'zenor' diodes, but Zener diodes, LEDs and Schottky diodes are types of diodes. They are named after Clarence Melvin Zener, an American physicist.
You can place a diode (D shortcut), right click on it 'pick a new diode' and choose from the drop-down list. For example, the BZX84C3V0.
You can also find models online such as this one from Diodes Incorporated by using your favourite search engine which is a composite model.
3V Zener diodes are not particularly good- they have a very soft 'knee'. You might consider using an LED or an IC such as the TL431 instead.

I am trying to get voltage regulation and my load cannot handle more than 3V thus I need zener didoe only 3vdc.  I do not want ICs or anything else as I want to build from components transistor diodes resistor etc

In general it is preferred to use a series voltage regulator such as AMS1117 or use an IC shunt regulator.

@hhsting I am nearly certain you will be disappointed with a zener in this application.
